# How to display data when one object is nil but the other isn't?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, tableview, addressbook

I have a tableView, similar to Contacts. The user can add his contacts in it and gets the names and the number displayed. When a contact only has a firstname and not a lastname he display the firstname and (null). In order to avoid it, I use an if-statement. But for some reason I always get a SIGABRT error at the line         `cell.textLabel.text = value;`.

Here is the code to obtain the data:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    lastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    number = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
    [thenumbers addObject:number];

if(lastName && ([lastName length] > 0)) {  
[menuArray addObject:[[Contacts alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName andLastName:lastName]];
   } else {
       [menuArray addObject:firstName];}


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
    }
```

And here the code to display it:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
if(lastName && ([lastName length] > 0)) { 
    Contacts *user = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [user firstName], [user lastName]]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
}  else { 
    NSString *value = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = value;

}

NSString *numbers = [thenumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = numbers;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGABRT means an exception was thrown. Look in the console log for the actual exception. I suspect you're actually getting it on the previous line:

```
    NSString *value = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The most likely error is that `indexPath.row` is past the end of `menuArray`.

---

**EDIT**: I think I see your error. It's actually probably a "does not respond to selector" error. When you build your `menuArray`, sometimes you add a `Contacts` and sometimes you add an `NSString`. (`Contacts` is a very strange name of this object; it seems to be a single person.) You never clear the old `menuArray`, and I suspect when you change `lastName` that you are winding up with stale information in there that then has a type-conflict later.

Also note that you're leaking `lastName` and `firstName`. You need `__bridge_transfer` here, not `__bridge`.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. Just tried again and I can add either persons with only firstname and it works or persons with first and lastname. If I try both I get the SIGABRT at the mentioned line. Any idea what I can do about it=

Comment: Thanks for your edit. So I should clear menuArray everytime one contact has been added?

Comment: You should clear menuArray before rebuilding it in `...shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`. Currently you just append to the existing array each time, but you change `lastName` which is used throughout the object. It's not clear from the above code what your goal is with `lastName` or with `menuArray`.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to do it? lastName is the last name of the contact and I save it in the menuarray. If there is no last name, just the first name, I want him to display just the first name and not fristname (null)

Comment: I did it myself. Weird thing is that when I add someone with firstName and lastName and after that someone with only the firstName, he deletes the lastName completely for all contacts..

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty dodgy mixing object types in the same array. It's probably worth checking that the objects are what you think they are, so where you say:

```
Contacts *user = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [user firstName], [user lastName]];
```

Try saying:

```
Contacts *user = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
if ([user isKindOfClass:[Contacts class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Okay, it's fine");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Oops, I messed up");
}
```

My hunch is that maybe sometimes it's a string when you're expecting it to be a Contacts object.

Comment: Hey it returns "Okay, it's fine"

Comment: I agree with Nick that mixing types in a single array makes me... nervous... I think your actual problem is your failure to clear menuArray, but the preferred solution would be to rework `Contacts` to handle first-name only (even better, just hand `Contacts` the `ABRecordRef`).

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know how to do that. Contacts is the viewcontroller btw. And yeah I did that before, only handling firstName, but sometimes people wanna have the lastName there, so I wanna leave that option open :)